# Drupal 7 with Mongodb

Tags: 7, database

I am working on Drupal website, and I heard about the MongoDB module. I installed and enabled it, but I don't understand how it works.

How can I switch all my data from MySQL to MongoDB?
Is it safe to purely depend on it? Can anyone tell me how to configure MongoDB with Drupal?

Comment: Google returns 131.000 results for the query ["drupal 7" mongodb](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22drupal+7%22+mongodb) so I think it should not be necessary to ask such a broad question here. I recommend that you read the documentation and blog posts out there and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 7):

You currently cannot use MongoDB for **all** your data. The [MongoDB module](http://drupal.org/project/mongodb) clearly states what it can store in your mongodb: Cache, Field storage, Session, Watchdog, Lock, Block and Queue. This cover most of your site data. But a SQL database will always be needed.

[This tutorial](http://groups.drupal.org/node/183279) gives configuration to put in your site settings.php to enable various MongoDB storage. But it may be outdated.

Comment: thanks for answering. i am totally confuse about mongodb. i am working on a application like facebook and i have a very large database.our client want to move on mongodb. is it a good decision to completely move on mongodb from mysql. if yes then how it is possible and is site is working properly without loss of data.

Comment: If you're jsut switching to mongodb for the sake of it, you're solving the wrong problem. The problem never is "we're not using mongodb". The real problem is probably related to performance, or a specific error. Communicate with your client and then start solving the *real* problem with an appropriate combination of mongodb and other technologies.